# some website's traffic didn't go through burp suite proxy

Tags: android, proxy, capture, traffic, burp

My problem is when I configure burp suite as a invisible proxy for my android phone. I can capture most website's traffic but I can not capture some website's traffic like facebook.

more information about my phone setting:
i route all tcp traffic from android to PC with command: `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
i redirect outgoing traffic to local host in android with 2 command:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8081
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -j MASQUERADE
```

thank for any help!

Comment: Some web sites contain data that pins their certificate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security This data is cached by the web browser. Try to clear the browser cache (inside the web browser, not the Android app cache) data to reset this data. Then the missing sites may also work.

Comment: i try to clear chrome cached in chrome setting not android setting as you said. but it didn't work. i even force close chrome
i use iptables to redirect udp protocol but i didn't work too(i though it was http/3)
when i disconnect pc to internet i get an error of burp suite with web sites i can capture. but missing sites work well. maybe it use mobile internet. so i think some wrong with iptables but i don't know what could go worng.

Comment: Note that to my experience recent versions of Chrome don't allow TLS interception at all as they only accept certificates mentioned in the certificate transparency log.

Comment: Because it not happen with all web site so it need to configure by web master somehow. Is that corretly?

Comment: By the way chorme can bypass iptables or it because my mistake. If all tcp packet through PC i should get an network error